# Array.Reverse algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

What kind of algorithm Array.Reverse(string a), uses behind the scene to reverse the string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably a standard in-place reversal algorithm.

> ```
> function reverse-in-place(a[0..n])
>  for i from 0 to floor(n/2)
>      swap(a[i], a[n-i])
> ```

#### Sources

- [Wikipedia/In-place algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)

Comment: This is a good answer in general. But notice the OP is asking about .NET (he clarified this in a comment). Reversing a string in-place in .NET is not possible without resorting to some evil tactics. And doing so by employing those tactics leads to bad things. See my answer!

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**: See the bottom of this answer for one truly horrifying ramification of reversing a string in-place in .NET.

---

### "Good" Answer

In .NET, there's no `Array.Reverse` overload that takes a `string`. That said, here's how one might be implemented if it were to exist:

```
static string ReverseString(string str) {
    char[] reversed = new char[str.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < reversed.Length; ++i)
        reversed[i] = str[str.Length - 1 - i];
    return new string(reversed);
}
```

Note that in .NET this method has to *return* a `string`, since the `System.String` type is immutable and so you couldn't reverse one in-place.

---

### Scary Answer

OK, [**actually, it *is* possible to reverse a string in-place in .NET**](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/are-strings-really-immutable-in-net/).

Here's one way, which requires compiling in `unsafe` mode:

```
static unsafe void ReverseString(string str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = str.Length - 1;

    fixed (char* fstr = str) {
        while (i < j) {
            char temp = fstr[j];

            fstr[j--] = fstr[i];
            fstr[i++] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's another way, which uses reflection and does **not** need to be compiled in `unsafe` mode:

```
static void ReverseString(string str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = str.Length - 1;

    // what a tricky bastard!
    MethodInfo setter = typeof(string).GetMethod(
        "SetChar",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
    );

    while (i < j) {
        char temp = str[j];

        setter.Invoke(str, new object[] { j--, str[i] });
        setter.Invoke(str, new object[] { i++, temp });
    }
}
```

Totally inadvisable and reckless, yes -- not to mention that it would likely have *horrendous* performance. But possible nonetheless.

---

### The Horror

Oh, and by the way, in case there's any doubt in your mind whatsoever that you should **never do anything like this**: be aware that either of the `ReverseString` methods I've provided above will actually allow you to write the following utterly bizarre program:

```
ReverseString("Hello!");
Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
```

The above code will output, believe it or not*:

```
!olleH
```

So yeah, unless you want all hell to break loose in your code, don't reverse a string in-place. Even though technically you can ;)

<sub>*You can try it for yourself if you don't believe me.</sub>

Comment: string is nothing but array of character (char[]), when you pass an string it think it as a char[].

FYI I could pass string and able to reverse it using Array.Reverse

Comment: Does it not depend on the encoding which string uses internally? Check out: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html

Comment: @ManojTrek: string is an alias to System.String, which is not 'nothing by an array of characters'. It contains a collection of chars within it, which you can get a copy of, but the String itself is immutable, and cannot be modified once created. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @ManojTrek: That is simply not true. A string may *internally* use an array of `char`, but it's not the same thing. You can modify the value at a specified index of an array; try setting `str[i] = 'c'` and you'll see it doesn't compile.

Comment: @ManojTrek: As for passing a string to `Array.Reverse`: just give it a try. You'll see it doesn't compile.

Comment: Aplogize, yes you are right need to use String.ToCharArray() method to convert to character array, before passing to Array.Reverse.

Comment: @MajojTrek: Just be aware that this is going to reverse *the array returned by `ToCharArray`*, which is a *copy* of the original string. Then, yes, you can easily create a new string from this reversed array. Again: **you cannot reverse a string in-place in .NET**.

Comment: @ManojTrek: ...er, addendum: you cannot reverse a string in-place in .NET *without using unsafe code* ;)

Comment: @ManojTrek: Yet another correction: you can do it even without using unsafe code (using reflection)! But, obviously, I don't advise it.

Comment: I laughed my ass off when read this. If you happen to have a bad manager you can hide it somewhere before leaving the company and watch them cry muhahah!

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm is probably using two pointers *i* and *j* that start at 0 and *length*-1 respectively. Then the characters at position *i* and *j* are swapped (with the help of a temporal variable) and *i* is incremented and *j* decremented by 1. These steps are repeated until both pointers reach each other (*i* ≥ *j*).

In pseudo-code:

```
i := 0;
j := a.length-1;
while (i < j) do
    tmp := a[i];
    a[i] := a[j];
    a[j] := tmp;
    i := i+1;
    j := j-1;
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Reflector, `Array.Reverse(Array)` (there's no string variation) first calls something called `TrySZReverse`, for which I can't find the implementation. I assume it's some sort of heavily optimized native method..

If that fails, it does something like this:

```
int num = index;
int num2 = (index + length) - 1;
while (num < num2)
{
    object obj2 = objArray[num];
    objArray[num] = objArray[num2];
    objArray[num2] = obj2;
    num++;
    num2--;
}
```

So, an in place algorithm, where it swaps the values at each end, then moves inward, repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general-purpose, language-independent, question-appropriate answer: It copies the input string to the output string, reading from one end and writing to the other.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
    private string Reverse(string text)
    {
        char[] c = text.ToCharArray(0, text.Length);
        Array.Reverse(c);
        return new string(c);
    }
```